# Compare two columns (one varchar, one int)

Tags: sql-server

I am constructing a temp table is sqlserver. Now in this temp table, I wanna check if one column integer value exists in another column's text field or not.

For ex. i have col. days which has values of 2,10,15,30... and so one multiple times and for each value, and another columns which has an entire text that has a description of set of rules and at the end, the timeline is 2 Calendar Days or 30 Calendar days or 10 Business Days which should match the integer column.

How do I compare the int value in the text matches in the rules text column?

For ex.

```
col1   col2
2      ....should happen....- 2 business days
4      ....should happen....- 4 business days
5      ....should happen....- 5 business days
6      ....should happen....- 6 business days
15     ....should happen....- 15 business days
30     ....should happen....- 30 business days
```

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx and http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: `SELECT LEFT(RIGHT(col2,13),2) AS col2, col1 FROM tempTable`

Comment: Does col2 always end with `... business days`? is the `-` before the number always present, and the only dash?

Comment: @aaron bertrand: the .... is just an expression, there are no dots but the yes, after the text ends, the format is "- 2 business days" or "- 1 business day" and so on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out int from the string like below. (Based on few assumptions: `only one '-' in the string before the number, number has left and right spaces`)

```
declare @s varchar(100) = '...should happen....- 20 business days'

;with cte as (
    select right(@s,len(@s)-charindex('-',@s,0)- 1) as rightText
)
select left(rightText, charindex(' ', rightText,0))
from cte
```

Query would be like

```
;with cte as (
    select col1, col2,
           right(col2,len(col2)-charindex('-',col2,0)- 1) as rightText

    from yourTable
 )
 select col1,col2
 from cte
 where left(rightText, charindex(' ', rightText,0)) = col1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM TEMP
WHERE col2 LIKE '%- '+cast(col1 as varchar)+' % days'
```

See [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed0f8/1/0)

Or may be :

```
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN col2 LIKE '%- '+cast(col1 as varchar)+' % days' 
            THEN 'Exists' 
            ELSE 'Not Exists' END AS "Exists"
FROM TEMP
```

See [**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ed0f8/4/0)

For msi77 :

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/302f2/1/0)**:

```
| COL1 |                                    COL2 |     EXISTS |
|------|-----------------------------------------|------------|
|    2 |  ....should happen....- 2 calendar days |     Exists |
|    2 | ....should happen....- 20 calendar days | Not Exists |
|    4 |  ....should happen....- 4 calendar days |     Exists |
|    5 |  ....should happen....- 5 business days |     Exists |
|    6 |  ....should happen....- 6 business days |     Exists |
|   15 | ....should happen....- 15 business days |     Exists |
|  999 | ....should happen....- 00 business days | Not Exists |
|   30 | ....should happen....- 30 business days |     Exists |
```

Comment: @msi77 Absolutly not a problem...see [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/302f2/1/0)

Comment: Something was changed. 
OK

Answer (score 0):

First, you can get the number from the varchar like this:

```
SUBSTRING(col2, CHARINDEX('-', col2) + 1, 2)
```

Then you can convert it into an INT like this:

```
CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(col2, CHARINDEX('-') + 1, 2))
```

[SUBSTRING](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

[CHARINDEX](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx)

[CONVERT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: getting an error:   Msg 189, Level 15, State 1, Line 1065
The charindex function requires 2 to 3 arguments.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add 'col2' in there as the 2nd parameter. It should be fixed now.